# Installing from an AMD onto Intel chip

Tags: system-installation

I am just starting out with Elementary OS and Linux as a whole. I created a copy of Elementary OS yesterday on a desktop with an AMD APU. I plan to install it onto my old laptop with an Intel APU. Will downloading from my AMD powered desktop change the source code, and if so will that mean I can't use the image I downloaded from the desktop? If it helps, both chips are 64-bit.

Answer (score 1):

There should not be any problem. Both Intel x86_64 CPUs and AMD64 CPUS implement the same specifications.